# Google chrome, searching in resources panel is not available any more?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Just now, I noticed I can't search in resource panel.

In Google Chrome old version, press Ctrl + F and there is nice search pop-up at the bottom in resources panel just like the image showing bellow.

[image]

Is it gone permanently or it can be enable somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Chrome Canary, as of this writing, follow these steps to search a tab:

1. Open Devtools
2. Press the Escape key to open the console drawer from any main tab (Resources, Source, etc).
3. Select the search tab on the console drawer (see image below)
4. Enter your search criteria
5. Press the Enter key

[image]

Comment: FYI, pressing Esc inside devtools toggles the console drawer.

Comment: I really prefer the old way which in my opinion was easier to use. This has already been changed in the Windows version and is in the Canary pipeline for OS X. :(